# is Christian philosophy possible? or can there be Christian philosophy?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

1. Introduction
2. Argument for Christian philosophy
3. Arguments against Christian philosophy
4. Conclusion in favour of Christian philosophy

NB: at least in 2 pages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we aren't here to write your paper for you.

Comment: Given that God is the source of wisdom (see Prov. 2:6), how can there be philosophy except for those who seek God to obtain it? A better question would be how philosophy is possible for those who deny God.

Comment: See here for relevant information: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/30541/what-is-the-difference-between-philosophy-and-theology/30555#30555

Answer (score 1):

There have been many very different philosophies advanced by Christians over the years. This suggests that there is no single thing called "Christian philosophy" but rather many philosophies defended by Christians. Apart from making room for a single deity, they have little in common. For example, Augustine was a platonist, Aquinas was an aristotelean, Descartes and Leibniz were rationalists, Locke was an empirical realist, Berkeley was an idealist, Kierkegaard was an existentialist, etc.