# What is Plantinga's "trivial property"?

Tags: logic, modal-logic, properties, plantinga

I have seen the term "trivial property" used several times, and some authors seem to be attributing it to Plantinga, but I cannot find his definition. I have seen others define it as a property necessary to x,  regardless of what you take x to be.

Answer (score 6):

Plantinga uses the concept of non-trivial properties in his transworld depravity defense of God's benevolence, see [How does free will defense of God's benevolence work?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/16301/how-does-free-will-defense-of-gods-benevolence-work) Ciprotti in [Theological Compatibilism and Essential Properties](http://nome.unak.is/previous-issues/issues/vol3_1/TC.pdf) discusses Plantinga's trivial and non-trivial properties with PDO (power to do otherwise, a.k.a. free will) as central example:

> "*According to him* [Plantinga], *a property P is trivial iff it constitutes a necessary condition for some thing to exist, e.g.  being self-identical, being P or not-P, and the like. To the contrary, PDO does not seem so:  for x to exist it is not required that x be free.*"

The reference for the definition is to Plantinga's Nature of Necessity (1974), Clarendon Press, NY, pp. 60-61. The notion of trivial is similar to what is called ["essential property" by Kripke](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/essential-accidental), but the sense of modality is strengthened from metaphysical to something close to logical. If an "essential property" is taken away from x it  would not be x anymore, but what is "left" can logically exist, while removing a trivial property makes even that impossible. Plantinga intends it to be somewhat stricter than just logical, e.g. "being a creature" might still be trivial in his context.