# If God is omnipotent, can he make self-contradictory objects?

Tags: theology

If God is omnipotent by definition, can he make self-contradictory objects such as colorless green ideas or something that exists and doesn't exist at the same time or long short objects.

Comment: Have you done any research on this paradox?

Comment: Ah, the mind loves its paradoxes! Can God create a stone so heavy that even He can't lift it? It's a game of words. In the realm of the infinite, contradictions dissolve. Embrace the mystery, and let go of the need to define God with the limitations of language.

Comment: -1 for lack of research is nnot consistent @CortAmmon except with the rules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the "omniscient-omnipotent-omnipresent" definition of God consistent?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/300/is-the-omniscient-omnipotent-omnipresent-definition-of-god-consistent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's up to you. God is a product of your imagination and omnipotence is a product of your imagination, so you are free to imagine whatever you wish. Some people in your shoes consider omnipotent to mean able to perform any act that is not self-contradictory, so if you went along with that crowd you  would say no, god cannot make square circles or circular squares. On the other hand, if you were more radical in your approach you might take the view that ruling out the ability to perform self-contradictory acts is an unnecessary constraint that we suppose because the human mind is incapable of escaping the constraints of logic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  An omnipotent being can choose what logic applies to this world, and can make a world which is self-contradictory if it chooses.

A key issue you should research if you want to think this thru more clearly is logical pluralism: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjvmrja7MuCAxWlEFkFHTIeCqQQFnoECCYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cambridge.org%2Fcore%2Fjournals%2Fthink%2Farticle%2Fguide-to-logical-pluralism-for-nonlogicians%2FEDFDFA1C9EB65DB71848DABD6B12D877&usg=AOvVaw2C6DDno0zMmxiU7BSOnVsZ&opi=89978449